# Selecting the positive solution only

Tags: inverse

This my first problem on Mathematica and I'm working on version 13.0, and I want to get the inverse z transform for an equation,
It works fine but it gives me the solution in the positive and negative part of the real x axis.

[image]

My question is how to make it gives only the solution in the positive part of the x axis.

Comment: "how to make it gives only the solution in the positive part of the x axis." Notice that `UnitStep[1 - k]* UnitStep[k - 1]=0` So you only have the term with `UnitStep[-2 + k]` which makes the solution start at `k>2` and zero for `k<=2`.

Comment: @Nasser - `Assuming[Element[k, Integers], 
 UnitStep[1 - k]*UnitStep[k - 1] // FullSimplify]` evaluates to `DiscreteDelta[-1 + k]` since `UnitStep[0] == 1`

Comment: Please post your Mathematica code here. Picture is not so useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

I am guessing that your `e` is actually meant to be `E`

```
f[z_] = (1 - E^-t) (2 z - 1)/((z - 1) (z - E^-t));
```

Note that `InverseZTransform` takes the option `Assumptions`

```
Options[InverseZTransform]

(* {Assumptions :> $Assumptions, Method -> Automatic} *)
```

Then,

```
Assuming[k >= 0, InverseZTransform[f[z], z, k] // FullSimplify]

(* Piecewise[{{2 - 2/E^t, k == 1}, 
     {1 + (-2 + E^t)/E^(k*t), k >= 2}}, 0] *)
```